# Obtener el listado de edades de una lista de Personas con recursión (Haskell)

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, haskell

Tengo el siguiente tipo Persona:

```
data Persona = LaPersona Nombre Edad 
type Nombre = String 
type Edad = Int


edad :: Persona -> Edad
edad (LaPersona _ edad) = edad
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para obtener el listado de edades de todas las personas de la lista de Personas?

Había pensado algo así, pero me quedé trabado.

```
edadesDePersonas :: [Persona] -> [Edad]
edadesDePersonas []= []
edadesDePersonas (p:ps) = edad p : (edad ps)
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo tenías casi hecho. Bastaba aplicar la función que estás definiendo recursivamente:

```hs
edadesDePersonas :: [Persona] -> [Edad]
edadesDePersonas []= []
edadesDePersonas (p:ps) = edad p : edadesDePersonas ps
```

Pero en este caso resulta más directo aplicar la función `map` (o mejor el genérico `fmap` para *functores*):

```hs
edadesDePersonas :: [Persona] -> [Edad]
edadesDePersonas ps = fmap edad ps
```

Y en notación *pointless*:

```hs
edadesDePersonas :: [Persona] -> [Edad]
edadesDePersonas = fmap edad
```